# How to transfer the server logins from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have migrate the database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012.
But how to transfer the server logins from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012?
The server logins are below the Server Security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following script on the 2000 SQL Server:

```
USE master 
GO 
IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_hexadecimal') IS NOT NULL 
DROP PROCEDURE sp_hexadecimal 
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_hexadecimal 
@binvalue varbinary(256), 
@hexvalue varchar(256) OUTPUT 
AS 
DECLARE @charvalue varchar(256) 
DECLARE @i int 
DECLARE @length int 
DECLARE @hexstring char(16) 
SELECT @charvalue = '0x' 
SELECT @i = 1 
SELECT @length = DATALENGTH (@binvalue) 
SELECT @hexstring = '0123456789ABCDEF' 
WHILE (@i <= @length) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @tempint int 
DECLARE @firstint int 
DECLARE @secondint int 
SELECT @tempint = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@binvalue,@i,1)) 
SELECT @firstint = FLOOR(@tempint/16) 
SELECT @secondint = @tempint - (@firstint*16) 
SELECT @charvalue = @charvalue + 
SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @firstint+1, 1) + 
SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @secondint+1, 1) 
SELECT @i = @i + 1 
END 
SELECT @hexvalue = @charvalue 
GO 

IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_help_revlogin_2000_to_2005') IS NOT NULL 
DROP PROCEDURE sp_help_revlogin_2000_to_2005 
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_help_revlogin_2000_to_2005 

@login_name sysname = NULL, 
@include_db bit = 0, 
@include_role bit = 0 

AS 
DECLARE @name sysname 
DECLARE @xstatus int 
DECLARE @binpwd varbinary (256) 
DECLARE @dfltdb varchar (256) 
DECLARE @txtpwd sysname 
DECLARE @tmpstr varchar (256) 
DECLARE @SID_varbinary varbinary(85) 
DECLARE @SID_string varchar(256) 

IF (@login_name IS NULL) 
DECLARE login_curs CURSOR STATIC FOR 
SELECT sid, [name], xstatus, password, isnull(db_name(dbid), 'master') 
FROM master.dbo.sysxlogins 
WHERE srvid IS NULL AND 
[name] <> 'sa' 
ELSE 
DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR 
SELECT sid, [name], xstatus, password, isnull(db_name(dbid), 'master') 
FROM master.dbo.sysxlogins 
WHERE srvid IS NULL AND 
[name] = @login_name 

OPEN login_curs 

FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @xstatus, @binpwd, @dfltdb 

IF (@@fetch_status = -1) 
BEGIN 
PRINT 'No login(s) found.' 
CLOSE login_curs 
DEALLOCATE login_curs 
RETURN -1 
END 

SET @tmpstr = '/* sp_help_revlogin script ' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
SET @tmpstr = '** Generated ' 
+ CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE()) + ' on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '/***** CREATE LOGINS *****/' 

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN 
PRINT '' 
SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name 
PRINT @tmpstr 

IF (@xstatus & 4) = 4 
BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group 
IF (@xstatus & 1) = 1 
BEGIN -- NT login is denied access 
SET @tmpstr = '' --'EXEC master..sp_denylogin ''' + @name + '''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN -- NT login has access 
SET @tmpstr = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [name] = ''' + @name + ''')' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
SET @tmpstr = CHAR(9) + 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @name + '] FROM WINDOWS' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication 
EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary, @SID_string OUT 

IF (@binpwd IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN -- Non-null password 
EXEC sp_hexadecimal @binpwd, @txtpwd OUT 
SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @name + '] WITH PASSWORD=' + @txtpwd + ' HASHED' 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN -- Null password 
SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @name + '] WITH PASSWORD=''''' 
END 

SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_POLICY=OFF, SID=' + @SID_string 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @xstatus, @binpwd, @dfltdb 
END 

IF @include_db = 1 
BEGIN 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '/***** SET DEFAULT DATABASES *****/' 

FETCH FIRST FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @xstatus, @binpwd, @dfltdb 

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN 
PRINT '' 
SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name 
PRINT @tmpstr 

SET @tmpstr = 'ALTER LOGIN [' + @name + '] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' + @dfltdb + ']' 
PRINT @tmpstr 

FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @xstatus, @binpwd, @dfltdb 
END 
END 

IF @include_role = 1 
BEGIN 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '' 
PRINT '/***** SET SERVER ROLES *****/' 

FETCH FIRST FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @xstatus, @binpwd, @dfltdb 

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN 
PRINT '' 
SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name 
PRINT @tmpstr 

IF @xstatus &16 = 16 -- sysadmin 
BEGIN 
SET @tmpstr = 'exec master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=''' + @name + ''', @rolename=''sysadmin''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

IF @xstatus &32 = 32 -- securityadmin 
BEGIN 
SET @tmpstr = 'exec master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=''' + @name + ''', @rolename=''securityadmin''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

IF @xstatus &64 = 64 -- serveradmin 
BEGIN 
SET @tmpstr = 'exec master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=''' + @name + ''', @rolename=''serveradmin''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

IF @xstatus &128 = 128 -- setupadmin 
BEGIN 
SET @tmpstr = 'exec master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=''' + @name + ''', @rolename=''setupadmin''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

IF @xstatus &256 = 256 --processadmin 
BEGIN 
SET @tmpstr = 'exec master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=''' + @name + ''', @rolename=''processadmin''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

IF @xstatus &512 = 512 -- diskadmin 
BEGIN 
SET @tmpstr = 'exec master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=''' + @name + ''', @rolename=''diskadmin''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

IF @xstatus &1024 = 1024 -- dbcreator 
BEGIN 
SET @tmpstr = 'exec master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=''' + @name + ''', @rolename=''dbcreator''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

IF @xstatus &4096 = 4096 -- bulkadmin 
BEGIN 
SET @tmpstr = 'exec master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=''' + @name + ''', @rolename=''bulkadmin''' 
PRINT @tmpstr 
END 

FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @xstatus, @binpwd, @dfltdb 
END 
END 

CLOSE login_curs 
DEALLOCATE login_curs 
RETURN 0 
GO

exec sp_help_revlogin_2000_to_2005 @login_name=NULL, @include_db=1, @include_role=1
GO
```

The copy/save the output and run it on the 2012 Server

For more info see [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246133)