# Syncronize logins with passwords between SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I have copied a database from SQL server A (Prod) to B (Test) for some testing purposes. I performed the backup and restore and was successful to restore the database to test server. As we all know the login and password has to be copied as well. I tried running [sp_help_revlogin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992) on the Prod server, copy the result, and execute the query on the Test server, but when I tried that I received an error message:

> The server principal '*******' already exists

Is there a way I could just update the password for those users to make sure that I have the similar login and password as in Prod.  I need to add logins that are missing and update any that already exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to copy a database (SQL Server 2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043726/best-way-to-copy-a-database-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I edited this question to make it clear that this question is about syncing logins between servers... not just making an initial copy of them.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about this script:
[How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992)

The script is also posted as an answer to this question:
[How to transfer the server logins from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231248/how-to-transfer-the-server-logins-from-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012/30231434#30231434)

You can add one line to this script to output code that checks if the login exists before the create statement.

```
print 'If not Exists (select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where name = ''' + @name + ''')'
```

It goes right after the lines that read:

```
SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name
PRINT @tmpstr
```

This will prevent the login from being created if it already exists. Then in order to update existing logins with passwords and other properties you can modify the line that reads:

```
SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, SID = ' + @SID_string + ', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
```

To this:

```
SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, SID = ' + @SID_string + ', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ';ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, CHECK_POLICY = OFF'
SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ';ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
```

and then the line that reads:

```
  SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
```

To this:

```
  SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS'
  SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ';ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
```

Full modified script:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_help_revlogin] @login_name sysname = NULL AS
DECLARE @name sysname
DECLARE @type varchar (1)
DECLARE @hasaccess int
DECLARE @denylogin int
DECLARE @is_disabled int
DECLARE @PWD_varbinary  varbinary (256)
DECLARE @PWD_string  varchar (514)
DECLARE @SID_varbinary varbinary (85)
DECLARE @SID_string varchar (514)
DECLARE @tmpstr  varchar (1024)
DECLARE @is_policy_checked varchar (3)
DECLARE @is_expiration_checked varchar (3)

DECLARE @defaultdb sysname

IF (@login_name IS NULL)
  DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR

      SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin FROM 
sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l
      ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name <> 'sa'
ELSE
  DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR


      SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin FROM 
sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l
      ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name = @login_name
OPEN login_curs

FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
IF (@@fetch_status = -1)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'No login(s) found.'
  CLOSE login_curs
  DEALLOCATE login_curs
  RETURN -1
END
SET @tmpstr = '/* sp_help_revlogin script '
PRINT @tmpstr
SET @tmpstr = '** Generated ' + CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE()) + ' on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */'
PRINT @tmpstr
PRINT ''
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
  IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
  BEGIN
    PRINT ''
    SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name
    PRINT @tmpstr

    print 'If not Exists (select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where name = ''' + @name + ''')'

    IF (@type IN ( 'G', 'U'))
    BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group
      SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS'
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ';ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
    END
    ELSE BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication
        -- obtain password and sid
            SET @PWD_varbinary = CAST( LOGINPROPERTY( @name, 'PasswordHash' ) AS varbinary (256) )
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @PWD_varbinary, @PWD_string OUT
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary,@SID_string OUT

        -- obtain password policy state
        SELECT @is_policy_checked = CASE is_policy_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name
        SELECT @is_expiration_checked = CASE is_expiration_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name

        SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, SID = ' + @SID_string
        SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ';ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, CHECK_POLICY = OFF'
        SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ';ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'

        IF ( @is_policy_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_POLICY = ' + @is_policy_checked
        END
        IF ( @is_expiration_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' + @is_expiration_checked
        END
    END
    IF (@denylogin = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is denied access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; DENY CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    ELSE IF (@hasaccess = 0)
    BEGIN -- login exists but does not have access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    IF (@is_disabled = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is disabled
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' DISABLE'
    END
    PRINT @tmpstr
  END

  FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
   END
CLOSE login_curs
DEALLOCATE login_curs
RETURN 0

GO
```